# For loop not executing at all?

Tags: java, for-loop, byte

So I have a program that deals with bytes. Everything works, except one part. A `for` loop doesn't execute at all.

This is the code...complex it is.

```
public int getID(int slot){
    int slots = 0;
    for(int a=0;a<b.length;a++){
        if(correctslot){ //condition not shown.
            if(slots==slot){
                System.out.println("found pair"); 
                for(int i=a;i<37;i++){
                    System.out.println("executing loop");
                    if(isID){ //condition not shown.
                        System.out.println("returning location");
                        return i+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            slots++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the program found a matching slot, it prints `found pair`. If it was executing the loop it prints `executing loop`, but that's the part that doesn't do anything at all. It prints the first string `found pair` but not the second `executing loop`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What are `correctslot` and `isId`? What is `b`?

Comment: Better put a println in there to see what `a` is at the start of the loop.

Comment: `b` is a byte array, `correctslot` compared the bytes in the array at the position to the bytes that I was looking for. The same goes for `isID`, it compared. But I think the variable `a` is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug `a` . I think `a >= 37` by the time either `correctSlot && slots == slot` .